# Python3 running on Mac but no Pip3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

I need to get `pip3` running on my Mac terminal for a project. I have `python3` installed, and I can run it, but when I try to run `pip3 freeze`, it says my command is not found.

I thought it would be automatically installed when I installed Python3. I tried to sudo install it, but it still didn't do anything. What can I do?

Comment: what specific version of Python are you using?

Comment: Does `pip` exist? If it does, what does `which pip` tell you?

Comment: How did you install Python 3? A python.org installer? Homebrew? Anaconda? Some other installer? Building the source and running `make install`?

Comment: @ElleSwan, would you mind answering the questions here, and if you have found a solution would you mind validating the answer that helped you?

Comment: `pip` is already bundled in recent versions of Python 3: `python3 -m pip --version`.

Answer (score 2):

Besides `brew install pip3`, in case `brew` is not installed on your Mac, you can install `pip3` via `get_pip.py` which can be found [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py). Assuming that `python3` is already installed, `cd` to the directory where you saved `get_pip.py` and run the file with `python3 get_pip.py`. This should get `pip3` installed on your machine.

Comment: exactly, can the ones who are downvoting at least explain why they are doing that, or if they think they are right, can they provide their answers?

Comment: I think Imiguelvargasf was downvoting competitively. I cannot demonstrate this, but I believe I saw his score go down after voting mine down. If this is false, I apologize in advance to him, but that's just what is seems like given that all the other posts had exactly 1 downvote before I downvoted his post.

Answer (score 0):

On my MacBook Pro (10.13.5), `which pip3` shows that it is located at `/opt/local/bin/pip3` but it is a symlink to `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3`.

This is the location of `python3` if you installed it via MacPorts. If you installed it with HomeBrew, then it would be `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/bin/pip3` (again, version might vary).

## Finding `pip3`

What I would do if I were you is first find out where your `pip3` actually is by either using `locate` or trying to manually find it by typing (Change 3.6 to whatever version you're on.) either:

```
$ /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3 --version
```

or:

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/bin/pip3 --version
```

You should see something like:

```
pip 9.0.3 from /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Otherwise, use `locate`:

```
$ locate pip3
```

As a last resort, the slow `find` can also be useful:

```
$ sudo find / -name pip3
```

## Build a Symlink

Then, make a symbolic link to that file in a path that is in your `$PATH` (again, ensure you replace the first path with the path to your actual `pip3`):

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3 /opt/local/bin/pip3
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using Python 3.4 or later in which `pip` is included by default, try the following command:

```
python3 -m pip freeze
```

When you use the `-m` command-line flag, python will search `sys.path` for the named module and execute its contents as the `__main__` module. ([more here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m))

This solution will allow you to use `pip` by `python3 -m pip`, but in order to use `pip3` directly you can:

- Install it via `Homebrew`:

  brew install pip3
- Install it with `get-pip.py`:

  curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
  python get-pip.py

Comment: This answer seems like a comment. Perhaps you should add some ways to either install pip3 or get pip3 into the path (I think on my MBP I did a symlink).

Comment: @GregSchmit, the problem is that I cannot provide a more specific answer since the one who asked the question is not providing further information. That is why I have added, _Assuming you are using Python 3.4+_

Comment: But after running that command, how would the user then be able to use `pip3`?

Comment: @GregSchmit, that is a good point, in case she needs to run `pip3` she won't be able to run it. I will update my answer.

Comment: Cool, and I am suspicious that you are competitively downvoting. I think your score went down from downvoting my answer, and all the posts besides yours had exactly 1 downvote prior to me downvoting your answer. I apologize if this is incorrect, but I wanted to let you know how it looks from behind my screen :)

Comment: @GregSchmit, I am also suspicious of you. I would like that everybody gives you a reason for downvoting you, but I guess that is the reason new users say SO is kind of unwelcome to new people.

Comment: I actually upvoted one of the other answers (flamenco's), which would be contrary to competitive downvoting. I thought your answer was just missing something (namely, how to actually fix the issue).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174979/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-greg-schmit).

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry if it seems like I'm giving minimal info. I'm a new compsci student so I am definitely not a pro but this seemed like a place to learn for sure! Is there a significant difference between pip and pip3? for some reason, bash is allowing me to run pip but not install pip3 (I've used both methods you suggested).

Comment: @ElleSwan, `pip` is a Python package that allows you to install other packages. `pip3` is the version of `pip` for Python 3.

Answer (score -2):

You could try `brew install pip3`. Or check where `pip` is installed, that might point to Python 3's version.